# Change Image in different languages from 'index.html' to 'about.html'

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick, multiple-languages

This is actually my first assignment to do the multiple language website which is 'English, Malay and Japan language'. I have 2 page html **('index.html' and 'about.html')** and I am done do the text translation and change image with different language. For **'about.html'** I have put  **'english.png'** as a default language, when I clicked **'Japan'** flag to change language, all text and image will change to **'Japan text' and 'japan.png'**. But when i go to **'index.html'** and return to **'about.html'**, it showed 'Japan text' and 'english.png'. it's supposed to show **'japan.png'**. How can I set on javascript if I choose **'Japan'** language, it will show **'japan.png'** even though I go to next page and return back to **'about.html'**.

My Code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smile9sue/xXn7e/11/)
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of code for such a seemingly simple task which belongs on the server

Answer (score 0):

You seem to set current language to 'en' at the beggining in this line:

```
jquery_lang_js.prototype.currentLang = 'en';
```

So, even though you are updating currentLang, it is getting reset. You can to use cookies or localstorage to store the currentLang and load the currentLang from there instead.